# What is the best way to seed data with a lot of information using EntityFramework Core?

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an entity configuration file and I seed data with the help of `HasData`, the example below.

```
public class PublicationConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Publication>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Publication> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(p => p.Image)
                .HasMaxLength(256)
                .HasDefaultValue("default-publication.png")
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.Title)
                .HasMaxLength(256)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.Value)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.PublisherId)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.CategoryId)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.HasOne(p => p.Category)
                .WithMany(categ => categ.Publications)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            builder.HasOne(p => p.Publisher)
                .WithMany(pub => pub.Publications)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            builder.HasData(
                new Publication {
                    Id = "publication-one",
                    Title = "the first publication",
                    Value = "the content of the very first publication on the web-site",
                    CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
                    CategoryId = "category-one",
                    PublisherId = "publisher-one",
                    Image = "image"
                },
                new Publication
                {
                    Id = "publication-two",
                    Title = "the second publication",
                    Value = "the content of the second publication on the web-site",
                    CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
                    CategoryId = "category-one",
                    PublisherId = "publisher-two",
                    Image = "image"
                },
                new Publication
                {
                    Id = "publication-three",
                    Title = "the third publication",
                    Value = "the content of the third publication on the web-site",
                    CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
                    CategoryId = "category-two",
                    PublisherId = "publisher-one",
                    Image = "image"
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have a property called `Value`, it's just a string, but I'm going to change it to an array of strings and add some real information meaning `Value` will contain over a thousand characters, moreover there are only 3 `Publications` here, but I want to add like 10 more. Thus my seeder will look huge and awful and I do not like it.

So I'd like to move this data anywhere else, maybe to a json file and then read the data from this file or maybe there is a better way, nevertheless I have no idea how I can do this and how to do this right.

The question is, what is the best solution to this problem? And I would be glad to see the solution code.

Comment: are you sure you want to have this in a migration? every time you run `database update` it will check if all the data is present in the database, and if you have so many records there it can be a costly, and more likely to fail, operation. I would make a seeder project that uses EF context to insert data that is read from a file and run it once on the database(/s) myself

Comment: This post gives good guidelines when to seed data in migrations https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding

Comment: I'm not sure, because I use migrations too often and having so much info that tracked by them is really a big problem. Could you send an example how to set up a seeder project as an answer to this post? @LLL

Comment: There's an example in the link I wrote earlier. Pretty much add a new console application project to your solution, with a reference to project that contains the EF `context` class, then build the `context` and use it to seed data that you read from a file. Then run it locally on your machine.

Comment: @LLL is the example you mentioned still present in the MSD link? I can see a link to a GitHub project but it doesn't contain any console application project as far as I know (I'm new to .NET). Or maybe you refer to the custom seeding logic in `Program.cs`?

Comment: @chick3n0x07CC there's a github sample in that link yes - https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/main/samples/core/Modeling/DataSeeding/Program.cs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do multiple data seeds by creating a json file.

Create a new method called `SeedLargData` in your PublicationConfiguration class.

In this method, get the data in the json file, convert it into `List<Publication>` , and return it to the Configure method.

```
 public class PublicationConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Publication>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Publication> builder)
        {
           builder.Property(p => p.Image)
            .HasMaxLength(256)
            .HasDefaultValue("default-publication.png")
            .IsRequired();

           builder.Property(p => p.Title)
            .HasMaxLength(256)
            .IsRequired();

           builder.Property(p => p.Value)
            .IsRequired();

           builder.Property(p => p.PublisherId)
            .IsRequired();

           builder.Property(p => p.CategoryId)
            .IsRequired();

           builder.HasOne(p => p.Category)
            .WithMany(categ => categ.Publications)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

           builder.HasOne(p => p.Publisher)
            .WithMany(pub => pub.Publications)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            builder.HasData(SeedLargData());
        }

       public List<Publication> SeedLargData()
        {
            var publications= new List<Publication>();
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"json file path"))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                publications= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Publication>>(json);
            }
            return publications;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cool. I'll try this. If it works I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: It works, but I created a static class and made this method reusable with the help of generics.

Answer (score 10):

The answer above works, but I made it reusable.

Here is the result.

```
public static class SeedHelper
    {
        public static List<TEntity> SeedData<TEntity>(string fileName)
        {
            string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string path = "Static/Json";
            string fullPath = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, path, fileName);

            var result = new List<TEntity>();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fullPath))
            {
                string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TEntity>>(json);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

I hope you understand that `"Static/Json"` is the path where my json files are located.

Comment: In my case, the file contains so much text that using this approach results in the error "Combined length of user strings used by the program exceeds allowed limit. Try to decrease use of string literals."  In my case I am using the `result` returned by `SeedHelper()` in the `modelBuilder.Entity<>().HasData()` method.